# Why to check base controller in createController() function?

Tags: php, controller

The question is: why to check if a parent class exists? Can you explain the exact functionality?

Here is my code:

```
 // create controller function 
    public function createController(){
        // check if controller class exists
        if (class_exists($this->controller)) {
            // create parents objects from controller, and check if class extend
            $parents = class_parents($this->controller);
            if (in_array('controller', $parents)) {
                //check if method exists
                if (method_exists($this->controller, $this->action)) {
                    // create and return new controller object
                    return new $this->controller($this->action, $this->request);
                }else{
                    echo "<h1>Method does not exist!</h1><br>";
                }
            }else{  // if base controller does not exist
                echo "<h1>Base controller does not exist!</h1><br>";
            }
        } else {    // if controller class does not extend
            echo "<h1>Controller class does not exist!</h1><br>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: you want to make sure that the class is loaded otherwise you'll get an exception.

Comment: Can you explain more, please?

Comment: @White159 If the class isn't loaded and you try to use it you will get an error. This prevents that from happening.

Comment: think of it like an if statement when you're reading an input from the user: you want to make sure that the value is what you're expecting.